# Game performance optimization interview

Tags: performance, optimization

This question came up:

You're searching for bottlenecks in your game, but nothing you're changing is making the game any faster, be it anything in the GPU pipeline or the CPU. Nothing is spiking, and the slowness appears to be distributed across everywhere. What do you do next?

I was flummoxed. Is it a trick question? When fixing perf issues, I always assume that this was the point at which you need to scale everything back. I don't think it's mem alloc, as that shows up in CPU perf.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure this is on-topic for SO. But we'll see how it goes...

Comment: I'd probably replicate on different hardware. Not sure it's what they're looking for.

Comment: Clearly you've found solution - "I'll post the question on SO and wait for results"... also I guess such answer would fail your interview.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I don't get it, but I guess if someone were to say that during an interview and the other person didn't have much of a humor it probably wouldn't end well.

Comment: @MxyL - was mostly kidding... but "wait for results" part is what will be an issue in interview. Question looks like starting point of conversation about cost of performance improvement vs. needs of game or some similar higher level topic. Having no suggestion on what to do next or randomly jumping between higher level suggestion and super low level one (like "not mem alloc") is likely not what interviewer looked for... Side note: anyway feels way too broad for SO - programmers or gamedev may be better places for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would have asked for more information. "Slow" is a poor indicator of bad performance and is a classification of a symptom rather than a symptom itself. For example, you might describe "slow" as being:

- Low frame rate
- Poor responsiveness to input
- High responsiveness and smooth framerate, but slow game mechanics (i.e.: the player and entities move smoothly but very slowly)
- In the case of networked games, apparent network lag

All of these problems have different potential causes and solutions:

- Low but consistent frame rate may be due to inefficiencies in your game loop. Simply running your favorite profiler may indicate that large amounts of time are spent in one particular piece of code. In a game I wrote, for instance, I discovered that low FPS was the result of a bad loop that calculated distances between entities multiple times without caching. In another game, I discovered that the data structure I was using to perform lookups against the terrain was `O(N)` rather than `O(1)` (python stdlib...ick). You can't diagnose a problem you can't see, and profiling is the first line of defense.
- Poor responsiveness may be due to a number of things. If the FPS is high but the controls are sluggish to respond, the API that you're using to access the controls may simply be bad. Some controllers may have crappy drivers that can kill responsiveness. It might even be your game loop: you might simply not be checking for input from the controller frequently enough (perhaps you're not checking on every tick). In one of the aforementioned games, I had an issue where certain actions had a delayed effect: you'd use an item and the game would respond a half second or so later. It turned out that the issue was caused by the client making a full round-trip to the server to perform the action, verify that it happened, and wait for the server to broadcast back that the item was used. Simply having the behavior take place instantaneously on the client remedied the issue.
- Slow game mechanics might indicate that game constants simply aren't set high enough. If everything is smooth and beautiful but everything just moves very slowly, it's quite possible that default velocities or accelerations aren't turned up enough.
- Network lag can be caused by any number of things: the router you're connected to might be failing, the VPS you're developing against might be on a host that's being DDoSed, you might be using a protocol that's overly (but uniformly) chatty, or you're simply sending too much data over the wire. In a piece of simulation software I wrote in college, the computations were performed on some beefy computers in a lab, while the visualizations were being run on my MBP in my dorm. It turned out that the sheer amount of data that I was sending from the lab computers to my dorm was enough to overload the cheap network switches in the building and drop packets, resulting in horrible lag but perfectly reasonable log output.

So I guess the answer here is to have the interviewer describe the symptoms more fully. @Ali's answer is great, but it could be that there's a more nuanced problem at hand that requires some coaxing to diagnose.

Comment: I can't upvote this answer because it doesn't respect the premise. The problem the interviewer was specifically uniformly slow code, and all that answer talks about pinpoint and identifiable issues.

Answer (score 1):

> You're searching for bottlenecks in your game, but nothing you're
>   changing is making the game any faster, be it anything in the GPU
>   pipeline or the CPU. Nothing is spiking, and the slowness appears to
>   be distributed across everywhere.

**It pretty much sounds like the definition of [Uniformly Slow Code](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?UniformlySlowCode).** Let's assume it is really what is meant by this (and not some I/O bottleneck or creation of unnecessary objects in a loop or some poor choice for the datastructures or for the algorithms, etc).

To make a uniformly slow code faster, you usually have to go against good practices, and that is why I usually stop optimizing my code when it is uniformly slow. (I suppose "stop optimizing" is not a good answer at an interview...)

One way to make things faster is to identify an appropriate sequence of small operations, collect them together in one place, and then manually improve the things; sort of "manually inlining" these operations then doing high-level simplifications on the code that emerges. It requires good intuition where this might be worth doing and excellent understanding of the involved code. [This answer calls it bunching and horizontal optimization.](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/131455/17394)

Another thing that might be worth looking into if your *really* have uniformly slow code is [Andrei Alexandrescu's optimization tips](https://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/three-optimization-tips-for-c/10151361643253920).

Comment: excellent answer. all the other fail to really answer. you may mention memory framentation and trying other allocators.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is about thinking about more efficient algorithms. "Micro-optimization" has its limits; you can perfectly optimize a bubble sort, for example, but to get real big speedup you'd invent another sorting algorithm.

Also, in games you may introduce different kinds of adjustable quality/speed (or precision/speed) tradeoffs. Typically all games have some settings that change graphic detail level.

Answer (score 0):

> anecdotal:

i can tell you what the problem is without actually knowing the answer to the question ;p

sloppy directx calls. too many objects. especially bad on some old dx9 games, since dx9 needed to make a new directdraw call for every object. or something like that, the story goes. basically resulted in the cpu waiting idle for the gpu to process all the messages.

although def not the solution to every issue, i though it was worth mentioning as an interesing piece of information ;p didn't see it in the other comments.

it's almost like having too many pixel shaders, except at least the gpu works at 100% with a mass of those :D good for frying omelettes. (also, using occlusion to save performance and then adding a mass of pixel shaders to that model is a BAD idea)

i hope you can see the humor in this ;p